# C# Change If to switch, how to handle "and"

Tags: c#, if-statement, switch-statement, case

So I have a task from a worksheet at work:

I have to change these Ifs to a switch, but how do i do it? Heres the Ifs:

```
if (i<0 || i>15)  Console.WriteLine ("A");
else if (i%5<2 && i/3>3)  Console.WriteLine ("B");
else if (3<i && i<10)  Console.WriteLine ("C");
else if (i&2==2)  Console.WriteLine ("D");
else  Console.WriteLine ("E");
```

and here is the switch i made, but that one is bad, but i dont know how to make a good one out of it, i hope you can help me with this.

```
switch (i)
    case (i<0):
    case (i>15):
        Console.WriteLine ("A“)
        Break;
    Case (i%5<2 && i/3>3) : 
        Console.WriteLine ("B“)
        Break;
    case (3<i && i<10) :
        Console.WriteLine ("C");
        Break;
    Case (i&2==2)  :
         Console.WriteLine ("D");
        Break;
    Default
         Console.WriteLine ("E");
        Break;
```

It doesnt have to run in a programm, it's just a task from a worksheet

Comment: what is the reason you need to use a switch?

Comment: Its a task from a worksheet at work

Comment: I think it can be done just wait a little...

Comment: FWIW I think the downvotes are a bit harsh here. Given the problem set, its a fair question IMHO

Comment: Switch to Visual Basic (no pun intended)

Comment: Im sorry if its a stupid question, Im new to programming and c# :(

Comment: @Mike: there are no stupid questions. Agree that the down votes are a bit harsh.

Comment: @EmilLundin: Have figured out what's going on. Its not really a question about the limitations of `switch` so much as getting the @Mike to understand the logic of the if statement itself (see my answer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't figured out all the rules completely, but I think what you're after is something like this:

The question wants you to realise that you've got a limited number of results, since the first rule is `(i<0 || i>15)`. This can be the default for a switch statement.

Then you need to work out what would happen for all integers 0-15 and write them into the rest of the switch.

So you're after something along the lines of (although this doesn't have your logic - you can figure that out so you understand what's going on):

```
switch (i) 
{

    case 0:
    case 2:
    case 5:
        Console.Write("Something")
        break;
    case 1:
    case 7:
        Console.Write("Something Else")
        break;

    default
        Console.WriteLine ("A“)
        Break;
}
```

Comment: I think thats what this is supposed to be, thanks! I hope i can make something out of that :)

Answer (score 3):

I think it's:

```
switch (i)
{
  case 4:
  case 5:
  case 6:
  case 7:
  case 8:
  case 9:
      Console.WriteLine("C");
      break;
  case 0:
  case 1:
  case 3:
  case 10:
  case 11:
  case 12:
  case 13:
  case 14:
     Console.WriteLine("E");
     break;
  case 2:
     Console.WriteLine("D");
     break;
  case 15:
     Console.WriteLine("B");
     break;
  default:
     Console.WriteLine("A");
     break;
}
```

Comment: @BOAndrew: Nicely figured out, although I was trying not to give the answer on a plate!

Comment: I didnt really get the task, but thanks to your answer @Jon Egerton, i  know that im stupid :D, Im gonna figure that out myself, but i may check back and look at this :) Thanks!

Comment: OK... maybe that was not so smart move from me to post the solution instead of how I would try to find it. But Jon, at least we don't have redundant answers :)

Comment: I solved it myself now, thanks to your  help Jon and Andrew :), i just didnt get that there is a logic behind these, i feel ashamed :(. I can just mark one answer as correct tho

Answer (score 2):

Use a separate variable, in which you have to embed the segmentation logic. Here is a sample:

```
//using enum
public enum MySwitchableVariable {
    NotDefined, //optional
    LessThanZero,
    MoreThanFifteen,
    RestOfFiveLessThanTwoAndFactorMoreThanThree, //its too complex to describe
    BetweenThreeAndTen,
    RestOfTwoIsTwo,
}
```

Then you have to make a function which takes an integer and spit out a case of this enum:

```
public MySwitchableVariable calculate(int i) {
    var result = MySwitchableVariable.NotDefined;
    // your implementation here
    return result;
}
```

finally you may switch that annoying variable like this:

```
var Variable = calculate(i);
switch(Variable) {
    case MySwitchableVariable.LessThanZero:
    // you know the rest
```

is that what you (or your instructor) want?

Comment: Im not sure, i dont think thats what he wants, I think its more like what Jon Egerton said, maybe that could help me, but thanks!

Comment: This is an interesting approach, although what you end up with in the `calculate` method is the original `if` statements, so doesn't really help in this particular instance.

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can't do this. Using the `switch` statement entails that the variable in `switch` can take a number of discrete constant values.

From the documentation:

> The switch statement is a control statement that selects a switch
>   section to execute from a list of candidates.

Furthermore,

> **Each case label specifies a constant value**. The switch statement transfers control to the switch section whose case label matches the
>   value of the switch expression (caseSwitch in the example). If no case
>   label contains a matching value, control is transferred to the default
>   section, if there is one. If there is no default section, no action is
>   taken and control is transferred outside the switch statement. In the
>   previous example, the statements in the first switch section are
>   executed because case 1 matches the value of caseSwitch.

Comment: I dont see why i get this as a task then :/

Comment: @Mike have this been assigned to you as a homework or have you been asked to do this in a job? Could you please give use more information (despite the fact that I think there aren't any more information) of what you have been asked? Thanks

Comment: yea, its just a task someone gave me. Its a worksheet with different Tasks on it to help me get into programming and C#. This one task just says, change these if statements to a switch statement, not related to any programm or anything, these are the only information i got tho.